# Launching a stored procedure .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures

```
Dim factory = New ContextFactory(connectionString)
            Using context = factory.[Get]()
                Using dbConnection As IDbConnection = context.Connection
                    Using spCommand As IDbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()
                        spCommand.CommandText = "sp_Test"
                        spCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        Dim parameter As IDbDataParameter = spCommand.CreateParameter()
                        parameter.ParameterName = "ID_PROG_PREL_1"
                        parameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32
                        parameter.Value = 1
                        spCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter)

                        Try
                            Dim res As Integer = spCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Catch ex As Exception
                        End Try
```

This piece of code locks the table on which the stored procedure acts but it doesn't work. Any suggestions or alternatives?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_Test] 
 (@ID_PROG_PREL_1  [int])
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.LOG_ERRORI
    (
    LOG_DATA
    , LOG_NOME
    , LOG_FINESTRA
    , LOG_COD_AZIONE
    , LOG_COD_ERRORE
    , LOG_DESC
    )
VALUES
    (
    @ID_PROG_PREL_1
    , @ID_PROG_PREL_1
    , @ID_PROG_PREL_1
    , 1
    , 1
    , @ID_PROG_PREL_1
    )

END
GO
```

UPDATE: this is the silly stored procedure that doesn't seem to work

Comment: can you please elaborate what problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm trying to launch a stored procedure from code but it doesn't work. 

I don't understand why as the code seems to work but the stored procedure doesn't.

Comment: Side note, do not prefix your stored procedures with `sp_` if you are using Sql Server. This is a reserved prefix for Microsoft's built in stored procedures.

Comment: An empty `Catch` block is *not* helpful, if the database happens to be creating an error. Get rid of that first.

Comment: define "doesn't work". ***what happens***, exactly, including any exceptions *in full*?

Comment: no exceptions at all, the code seems alright but the stored procedure doesn't execute.

Comment: @zombiechainsaw are you *sure* there's no exceptions? (you are swallowing them, after all - you have a `Catch ex` that does nothing except drop it on the floor and disregard anything bad that happened) - and what makes you think it isn't executing? *tell us the symptom*. We don't know what `sp_Test` does, so : why do you suspect it isn't working? Where are you looking?

Comment: @MarcGravell sp_Test makes a simple insert into a table. i've removed the try catch (i was in debug anyway), the code works fine but the database insert doesn't

Comment: launch profiler and see if it is actually calling the stored procedure and use that call statement to manually test if stored procedure is returning the correct output. [note:- if you dont know how to use profiler then search google]

Comment: @zombiechainsaw right; now - what database are you using? is it a standalone SQL Server, or it it a database file? if the file: are you sure you're looking in the right one? remember that the file in the *executing* code is different to the file in your solution explorer. If a server: are you sure you're looking under the right name? it is easy to connect to a different server or as a **different user** - meaning: you end up looking at the wrong table (there can be multiple `[SomeTable]` tables, each in different schemas in the same database - which one gets chosen depends on *who you are*)

Comment: Finally: have you executed the SP with the same parameters via SSMS to see what happens there?

Comment: As for the general "how to launch a stored proc"  personally, I strongly recommend tools like dapper here, which make it harder to screw up. I don't know the VB syntax for anonymous types, so I'll drop down to C# - sorry, but: `var res = context.Connection.Execute("sp_Test", new { ID_PROG_PREL_1 = 1 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`- which does *everything* in your code, and a few other things (like: opening the connection if needed, and closing it afterwards if it did)

Comment: @MarcGravell it's a database on a server, the access to tables works fine so that's a confirmation that the db is right. i've tried with the profiler and it doesn't track anything, tried the SP from SSMS and works just fine

Comment: @zombiechainsaw this sounds like a configuration thing; I'd start by looking at the connection string, then I'd probably add code that does `select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME();` - to find out where I'm actually running (as as whom) - compare and contrast the output of that between your running code, and SSMS

Comment: @MarcGravell tried your solution, the configuration seems fine! don't know what other stuff i can check honestly.

Comment: Dim queryResult3 As String = context.ExecuteNonQuery("EXECUTE sp_Test 1")
 tried this one as well but it doesn't do anything